# My form getting submitted twice. Once during onsubmit event and again when bootstrap validator called

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below you can see I am calling one function on submit of the form, name validate_mainform(). I have checked in my application well even by renaming the function that its calling only once. But if I put an alert the alert showing twice.

After lot of debugging what I found is problem resides in the piece of code below.

**Bootstrap_validate.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mainForm').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'enabled',
        fields: {
            reg_date: {
                group: '.col-sm-3',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter the Registration Date'
                    }
                }
            },
            proj_name: {
                group: '.col-sm-10',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter the Project Name'
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

If I comment out the above call to bootstrap validator then the function called once.

Below is the code for my form and the function.

**project_reg.php**

```
    <form id="mainForm" method="POST" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="return validate_mainform();">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit_button" id="btn_submit_id"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" name="save_button" id="btn_save"/></br>
                <br />
                <p><strong><a href="https://arecontvision.wufoo.com/forms/report-a-problem/" target="_blank">Report a Problem</a></strong></p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php require_once('Bootstrap_validate.php'); ?>
```

Finally my function which is called on submit

**validate_mainform()**

```
    function validate_mainform() {
        if ($('#mainForm').length > 0) {
            alert('Here coming twice');
                if($('input#btn_submit_id').attr('clicked')) {
                    return get_validate_output();
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        } else {
            return get_validate_output();
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

I removed validate_mainform call from onsubmit and added onclick of save. Now as you can see inside validate_mainform() I am calling another function get_validate_output(). If the function returns false then I need to prevent form submission . Can you please tell me how to do that?

```
 function get_validate_output() {
    var output =  get_result();
    if (output == PRODUCT_VALID.AT_LEAST_ONE) {
        $('.itemidclass').addClass('error-product');
        $('.at-least-one').text('Please Add at Least One Product');
        return false;
    } else if (output == PRODUCT_VALID.ALL_VALID) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if ($('.itemidclass').hasClass('error-product')) {
            $('.itemidclass').removeClass('error-product');
            $('.at-least-one').hide();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

return false won't work now. As I am calling onclick event now. SO Instead of doing return false what else I can do to prevent form submission.

Comment: that is because you don't need to have both `bootstrapValidator` and onsubmit javascript validation. If both validation are successful, both of them submits the form.

Comment: I removed validate_mainform call from onsubmit and added onclick of save. Now as you can see inside validate_mainform() I am calling another function get_validate_output(). If the function returns false then I need to prevent form submission . Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: It seems like you want both validations, `bootstrapValidator` should provide a means of doing some custom validation. Unfortunately, [it is no longer supported](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator). I'd suggest moving to http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ - you can embed custom validation logic in it.

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrapValidator` has it's own submit handler, you are validating twice.

Remove `validate_mainform()` entirely it is useless. Remove `onsubmit="return validate_mainform();`" This is the WRONG way to validate with the plugin.

Your form should have 1 submit button:

`<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Validate </button>`

When this button is clicked the BootstrapValidator will handle the validation you can use `success.form.bv` to catch the event.

```
 $('#mainForm').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'enabled',
        fields: {
            reg_date: {
                group: '.col-sm-3',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter the Registration Date'
                    }
                }
            },
            proj_name: {
                group: '.col-sm-10',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter the Project Name'
                    }
                }
            }

        }).on('success.form.bv',function(e)
         {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('im ready to submit');
         }

    });
```

Comment: No validate_mainform is not useless. I need that to validate some of fields in the form in my custom way. And on submit I need to check those fields validation. I can't remove that function. Any other solution  ?

Comment: BootStrapValidator can handle any type of validation even if you need to validate it against a regex field. You can also run custom validation from inside the validator.

Comment: I removed validate_mainform call from onsubmit and added onclick of save. Now as you can see inside validate_mainform() I am calling another function get_validate_output(). If the function returns false then I need to prevent form submission . Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your forms action to action="javascript:return;". This will disable the auto form submitting.

```
 <form id="mainForm" method="POST" action="javascript:return;" class="form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="return validate_mainform();">
```